# QSlider - how to color the space

Tags: qt, qslider

i need to design my QSlider ...

I have start point and end point on the slider bar

the start point and the end point is movable by the user

now i need to color the space between the start point and the end point

Please let me know your helps and suggestion on this

Answer (score 2):

Link for Qt 4.8 (slider customization):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider

Answer (score 0):

In general for coloring task "[Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html)" is very useful.